# Drop down box value changes

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I started creating an automation framework for my current company. now I’m having a problem with a form that has a JS modal appearing top part of the form attaches to it. that JS form comes every time if I change the default value of the form (Changes Detected: save button, dismissed button). the issue is there is a drop-down box and the default value is set to empty. after I change that to a value (eg: house) that JS modal comes that I have made a change to the form and put the value of the drop-down box to that default empty value. this happens in the run time. if I put a thread.sleep for 3 seconds that solves the issue. but I need a more reliable solution. are there any other options that I can use for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

All I can think of now is to call that first function, Wait for success

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.javaScriptThrowsNoExceptions("putValue()"));
```

May be a little bit

Comment: thank you for the reply and spending your time looking into this. yeah I'll try that